# VS2019 hints to clean up code seem to indicated that defining variables at the begging of a routing like we have done for years is no longer necessary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

According to the hints in code cleanup, I do not need to define byte[] sqlImage.  If that definition is removed, then I get a message that sqlImage has not been defined.

```
        byte[] sqlImage = new byte[0];
        sqlImage = (byte[])foundRows[0].ItemArray[2];
```

I would appreciate it if someone would explain what I'm missing.  Thanks

Comment: Besides the duplicate, the official docs are a great place to get started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are reassigning sqlImage on second line

```
sqlImage = (byte[])foundRows[0].ItemArray[2];
```

thus, following line is unnecessary

```
byte[] sqlImage = new byte[0];
```

you can simplfy it

```
var sqlImage = (byte[])foundRows[0].ItemArray[2];
```

Comment: In the following lines of code, I get the message about the unnecessary assignment when I define the variable for getPhotoID but not with NewID.  I understand I could simplify as you showed, but that is not one of the options given.  Shouldn't you
define your varialbes before usinging them, which is what I've been doing for years.

            string getPhotoID;
            getPhotoID = AncestryID.ToString() + "-" + DocID.ToString();

            string NewID;
            NewID = Convert.ToString(rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop + 1);

Comment: Thanks Dervis, that helps.

Comment: sqlImage is a byte array, which is how I defined it.  Defining variables for their specific use has always been the preferred way to define variables.  Defining variables at the begging of code makes it easier to understand and read code.

Comment: @Charles **Defining** and **assigning** an array are two different things. You can **define** a byte array without giving it a value. It does not make sense to **assign** a value and then immediately assign a different value on the next line.